# Deploying SCCM Application with System rights and User Part

Tags: sccm

I want to deploy a Software with a .msi Installation in System context and copy configuration files for every users appdata that will login to a machine. 
Msi installation isn’t a Problem. But how do I deploy system and user context in a single collection?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two different Applications one that is deployed per machine and one that is deployed once per user (if it is an application you can just set the detection method right and it will be installed once for every user, if it is a program you have to set it to "run once for each user that logs into the computer".

You can deploy both those applications to the same collection without problem. There is no limit as to how many applications can be deployed to the same collection. If for some reason the user part has to be run after the machine part you can set the one application as dependency of the other (or for a program use "run another program first")

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old but I couldn't leave it like this.

Syberdoor's answer is misguided, owing to a misunderstanding of how MSIs work. There's no need for 2 applications at all.

In the MSI, rearrange the feature so that the feature containing the user-level component becomes a parent of a feature containing an advertised component. Normally, this will be the shortcut to the EXE. For vendor-supplied MSIs - remember, we *never* mess with vendor's MSIs - use a transform to make these changes.

Now, when the user clicks the shortcut, the feature-checking in the MSI will trigger self-healing, because the user's profile won't contain the relevant component.